# Formatting file inputted text in char array?

Tags: c, arrays

I have a file.txt which contains a certain string of text. Lets say the string is, without quotations "xDfS2\0dj\0\0aj"

First I put this text into a char array, which I have accomplished by using fopen and fread to input the text into `char *workingarray;`

My problem comes in the form of trying to print this array. (Using printf) I want to print the array character by character, but each time it reads `'\0'` I want it to go to a new line.. so the output of `workingarray` would be..

```
xDfS2 
dj

aj
```

I'm trying to accomplish this in way right now..

```
for( i=0; i <= length; i++ ) {
    if( workingarray[i] = '\0' ) {
        printf("\n");
    } else {
        printf( "%c", workingarray[i]);
    }
}
```

Now this doesn't work because it doesn't see the first the \0's as `'\0'` but as `'\'` and `'0'`, two separate fields in the array. I've also tried only searching for `'\'` by using `'\\'` in order to compensate for the fact that it's an escape sequence but this just gives me a segmentation fault and core dumb when trying to run it.

I've also tried making a second array that is based off of the first but takes the `'\'` from the first and make it a `'\0'` in the second while ignoring any `0` in the first instead, like this.

```
int k = 0
length = sizeof(workingarray);

for(i=0; i <= length; i++) {
    if( workingarray[i] = '\\') {
        newarray[i-k] = '\0';
        k++;
    } else if ( workingarray[i] = '0' ) {
        return;
    } else {
        newarray[i-k] = workingarray[i];
    }
}
```

Long story short is.. I'm not sure how to do this. How can I input a string of text from a file (the entire file, not just a certain part of it) and then print it that string out whilst creating new lines for every \0 in the string?

Comment: Perhaps `for(i=0; i <= length; i++)` --> `for(i=0; i < length; i++)`  `<+` to `<`.

Comment: It would be informative to see how you read your file into workingarray. If you declare char *workingarray and just use it for reading straight out, then chances are you will crash if you do not allocate memory and store its address in workingarray. Also, you seem to want to check againt the charater zero rather than the NULL character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have actual `'\\'` and `'0'` in array instead of `NUL`, then just do

```
for( i=0; i < length; i++ ) {
    if( workingarray[i] == '\\' && workingarray[i+1] == '0' ) {
        i++;
        printf("\n");
    } else {
        printf( "%c", workingarray[i]);
    }
}
```

Note also that you need to use `<` in for-loop instead of `<=`, and comparison needs to use `==` and not `=`.